# Safe conversion to Word8

Tags: haskell

Take a look at the following snippet:

```
Prelude> import Data.Word
Prelude> data Foo = Foo Word8 deriving Show
Prelude> Foo 4
Foo 4
Prelude> Foo 44
Foo 44
Prelude> Foo 444
Foo 188
```

I'm a bit surprised that 444 is implicitly converted to 188 like in unsafe C. It looks pretty error-prone to me. What's the idiomatic way to deal with such conversions safely in Haskell?

**UPDATE**

It seems this is just polymorphic behavior of literals and modern compiler warns about this. The most important is that type system doesn't allow such implicit truncation. `Foo (444 :: Int)` generates type mismatch, so this is completely safe if value is known in run-time only.

Comment: Why would it be unsafe?

Comment: @Arnon updated the question. I thought it behaves this way not only for literals, but for arbitrary values (read from stdin for example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A warning was recently added to GHC to call out cases such as this.  With GHC 7.8.3 I see:

```
Prelude Data.Word> Foo 444

<interactive>:7:5: Warning:
    Literal 444 is out of the Word8 range 0..255
Foo 188
Prelude Data.Word>
```

And when compiling:

```
$ ghc so.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )

so.hs:5:19: Warning: Literal 444 is out of the Word8 range 0..255
```

So the idiomatic solution is to use the latest version of the most popular compiler.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that type system allows implicit truncation of integers like in C (Int to Word8). It seems this is just polymorphic behavior of literals and `Foo (444 :: Int)` generates type mismatching. So, this is pretty safe actually.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about idiomatic, but the problem you're experiencing basically that a literal is being truncated when it's out of bounds.  Since literals are polymorphic on `Num`, and `Integral`s require `Num` as well, you have the functions

```
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
toInteger :: Integral a => a -> Integer
```

So you can always compare them as `Integer` before conversion:

```
-- Don't export the constructor
data Foo = Foo Word8 deriving (Eq, Show)

foo :: Integral a => a -> Maybe Foo
foo x = if xI > mBW8I then Nothing else Just (Foo $ fromInteger xI)
    where
        xI = toInteger x
        mBW8 :: Word8
        mBW8 = maxBound
        mbW8I = toInteger mBW8
```

Then you can use `foo` as a smart constructor:

```
> foo 4
Just (Foo 4)
> foo 44
Just (Foo 44)
> foo 444
Nothing
```